# Stop censoring Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion

There is no legitimate reason for deleting this [Answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/46001/28734) at [Earliest story?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/45632/earliest-story). Why has this [Answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/46001/28734) been deleted? Because scholars that are the direct descendants of the African Ancient Egyptians challenge and repudiate western academia?

Your site has demonstrated a pattern of deleting questions and answers, which amount to outright censorship. Stop censoring historical questions and answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my answer deleted?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/why-was-my-answer-deleted)

Comment: @T.E.D. The link is not relevant. Your site is essentially censoring any content that is not liked by moderators. Your site evidently has nothing whatsoever to do with actual history, but rather your site is centered on the _opinion_ of moderators. Citations were asked for and citations were provided. We do not need to agree with your _opinion_, especially where our own scholars have published evidence refuting the accepted _opinion_ of western academia. Again, stop censoring legitimate questions and answers relevant to history. Your censorship effectively makes your site an absolute fraud.

Comment: @T.E.D. Your sites' censorship of questions and answers proves that your site is not interested at all in any perspective other than moderators; that western academia cannot be challenged or refuted at all; that the only acceptable citations and references are those of the very western academia that is being challenged and refuted. Is your sites' official policy that the opinions of western academia as to history _cannot_ be challenged and refuted?

Comment: If your sites' official policy is that a challenge or refutation of western academia requires a published _book_, _The Historical Origin of Christianity_ by Walter Williams (1998) satisfies such an unstated requirement; which within the books pages, refutes the claims of western academia that the African Ancient Egyptian MDW NTR ("hierogplyphics") has ever been or ever will be "deciphered" (an interview of the author is linked at the referenced Answer). Kindly un-delete the above referenced Answer and stop censoring questions and answers, as you only prove that your site is _not_ about history

Comment: If your claim is that the linked videos are "offensive", then stop offending the direct descendants of the African Ancient Egyptians by claiming that Young or Chompollion (western academia) somehow "deciphered" the _secret_ language of the African Ancient Egyptians, which is not a _phonetical_ language in the first instance. Chompollion's _peers_ themselves challenged and refuted his claims of deciphering the MDW NTR at the time of Chompollion's life. Though we need not rely on those peer reviews, we are quite capable of composing our own scholarship relating to our own history in our own way.

Comment: @T.E.D. Included the citation to the _published book_ refuting the claim that Chompollion "deciphered" the MDW NTR ("hieroglyphics") of the African Ancient Egyptians at the linked Answer. If the reason for deleting the answer is citing a published _book_ (though your site allows citation of Wikipedia) there can be no rational excuse  for deleting the Answer. The only reason for deleting the Answer is decidedly actively engaging in history revision and censorship at a site purporting to be about _history_ - not "western" history or western academias' opinions of history, but history itself.

Comment: https://twitter.com/guest271314/status/992853447937376256

Comment: If viewers of this question are not able to view the linked youtube videos, these are the links to the videos refuting the claim that the African Ancient Egyptian MDW NTR ("hieroglyphics") have been or ever will be "deciphered": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACZ4k_c-fIk, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsVjdzKDjuI

Comment: Primary source verification from the perspective of western academia as to why the African Ancient Egyptian MDW NTR ("hieroglyphics") have not been and shall never be "deciphered": _"Strictly speaking, all the letters of the Egyptian Alphabet are consonants... In reading a text the Egyptian reader himself supplied the vowels, and it is for this reason that we shall never know accurately how the reader pronounced their words."_ _The Rosetta Stone_ by E. A. Wallis Budge (British Museum)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my answer deleted?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/why-was-my-answer-deleted)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seek an answer. It seeks to make a statement to vent out the OP's dissatisfaction.

Answer (score 12):

Your "answer" was not actually an answer to the question, which is "the earliest story". Instead, you used the opportunity to soap box your conspiracy theory on hieroglyphics. It is clearly an extended comment on T.E.D's Egypt based on answer and not an actual answer to the question.

That is why it was flag as "not an answer" and deleted accordingly by a moderator.

If you wish to talk about hieroglyphics, you should ask a question on it specifically, and post your theory as an answer.

[Read this for more details.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: There was no "Mesopotania" is actual history. That is an invention of western academia. Your answer to the question asserted the absolute falsehood that the African Ancient Egyptian hieroglyphics have been somehow translated to English. Stop telling that lie.

Comment: Your entire site appears to be a soapbox for theories of western academia. Your site actively censors any content which challenges and repudiates the claims of western academia. Your site is not about actual history at all. Rather, your site is solely concerned with censoring any content that the moderators do not agree with. That is not scholarship nor the study of history, but plain censorship.

Comment: @guest271314 Look, it's very simple. If you want to write about hieroglyphics, go ask your own question to answer with. Despite your persecution complex, you are completely free to be as wrong as you want to be - as long as it's on topic. Writing a non-answer to comment on another answer, however, is not allowed. And TED's answer is an answer, not a question - no matter how many times you pretend it is. Continuous bickering in the comments only serves to indicate you are not behaving in good faith.

Comment: I would add that this answer should not be taken as an endorsement of posting personal historical theories that are way outside the mainstream on History.SE. This isn't a place to be conducting novel historical arguments, but rather for *accurately* reporting what the current state of that scholarship is. Revisionist or non-mainstream ideas should be presented as such, To do otherwise is maliciously misleading to those who don't have the time or knowledge to double-check all your sources.